# How to take screenshot all preview layout on eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, testing, resolutions

I'm android developer.

My question is how to take screenshot all preview layout on eclipse.

I means we can see the preview all screens using graphical layout on eclipse.
Then, how to save images these screens separately for device resolutions.
Actually, I could do it manually using screenshot buttons but it will takes many times if there is a lot of xmls.

Q1. Is there script or open source to save image on various resolution using android xml?

Q2. If we don't enough android devices how to test various screen sizes?
Is there any best way to this?